# RDP from Win10 to Win11

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, windows-11

Whenever I try to RDP into my Win 11 Pro machine from any Win 10 machine, the results seem to be very sporadic as to whether or not it will actually work.

From one Win 10 machine in particular, the RDP client *appears* to connect successfully to the Win 11 machine and brings up a black screen (at which time the logged-in user on the Win 11 machine is disconnected like you'd expect), but then... nothing. The desktop never appears. Instead, after about 10 seconds, I get an error:

[image: Your Remote Desktop Services session has ended.]

Now, I am attempting this on a corp. domain.  Could this be a(nother) Windows 11 "feature," or is this more likely some kind of firewalling issue on the network?

Testing port 3389 from to domain Win 10 machine to the Win 11 machine using [PortQry](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/portqry-command-line-port-scanner-v2#commandline) yields the following:

`TCP port 3389 (ms-wbt-server service): LISTENING`

`UDP port 3389 (ms-wbt-server service): LISTENING or FILTERED`

Using the same tool on a *known-working* RDP connection yields the exact same output, which would seem to suggest that the network may *not* be the issue.

Comment: Most likely the latter.  I've had no trouble RDP'ing between multiple Windows 10 and 11 Pro desktops daily, for hours (sometimes days) at a time.

Comment: One has to actually enable RDP permissions in order to RDP into a machine regardless of its Windows 10 or Windows 11

Comment: @Ramhound - Very aware of that. RDP is already turned on and it works from other machines. If RDP wasn't enabled, I would never even get the beginning of a connection at all.

Comment: To answer your question if it’s a Windows 11 feature, it’s not, you being disconnected from your session unlikely has anything to do with Windows 11

Comment: @Ramhound - Tongue in cheek my friend. And in all actuality, I've had a *lot* of things go wrong precisely *because* of using Windows 11 (things that weren't an issue in 10 on the same machine). I don't find it far-fetched at all that this is one more loose end that M$ failed to tie up properly.

Answer (score 1):

Scrap it all.  Windows 11 was kicking the laptop off of the already-connected Wi-Fi once the local terminal session was disconnected by the RDP initiation. I had to manually enter the Wi-Fi credentials *directly in the login screen* to reconnect it.

I've never seen anything like this before, so I'm guessing that this *disconnecting you from Wifi when "locking" the machine* is a Windows 11 "feature" that isn't supposed to happen when RDP is used, but seems to be happening anyway.

Further testing shows that Windows 11 *won't* maintain this connection after reboot, despite setting the network to "connect automatically," and thus appears to require you to manually reinitiate the Wi-Fi from the login screen if you don't log in.

Comment: Probably worth asking a separate question on it (although search for a potential duplicate first).  My laptop is Windows 10, with two Windows 11 desktops, so I'm not sure.  I guess I could try with WiFi on one of them to see.  Any chance it's related to a laptop "Power Plan"?

Comment: That sounds like a WiFi adapter setting. No; Disconnection after the computer is locked is either a WiFi Adapter setting or a group policy neither would be specifically unique to Windows 11. Have a Windows 11 machine that stays locked, connected to a wireless network 24/7, unless I remotely accessing it with TeamViewer

Comment: In Windows 10, I have never had to enter Wi-Fi login information on the lock screen for wifi to stay connected when the screen is locked. It wouldn't connect even though it was *already* connected to that same network before locking. This is novel to Win 11 as far as I am aware. No group policy has been set to do this, it's my machine.

Answer (score 1):

I have the exact same problem. This is more of a workaround than an answer, but maybe a clue to a better answer.

I have noticed this happens only when connecting Win10 -> Win11 via OpenVPN from a particular corporate site that has a more stringent firewall and doesn't occur over same VPN from a different site with a more lax firewall or same site Win10 -> Win10. It doesn't happen when connecting on my LAN from Win10 -> Win11. And, interestingly, when what you describe does happen over the VPN on Win10 -> Win11, I can go Win10 --VPN--> Win 10 --LAN--> Win11 no problem. That has been my workaround until MS fixes this. Of course this workaround only works if you have a second computer on the same LAN.

Comment: I've had to downgrade remote Winodws 11 computers to window 10 (disabling secure boot so they won't auto-upgrade to 11), in order for them to RDP to Window 10. If the home user using Windows 11, they get a black screen upon RDP to Windows 10. There's not Microsoft fix insight. I have TCP and UDP open on the firewall for port 3389. When I block UDP, they can see their desktop upon RDP, but can't interact with it. With UDP enabled they see only a black screen. What a mess. I've been dealing with this for several months.